# python infix to Postfix (calculator)

Tags: python

I have a homework to make a calculator(infix-to postfix)
I get an syntax error when I run this code(invalid syntax **if expr***:* How do i fix this error code?

By the way I am a new programmer,the question could be simple for experts.I will be very pleased, if you could just give the answer as soon as possible.

```
class Op:
def __init__(self, num_in, num_out, fn):
    """
    A postfix operator

    num_in:     int
    num_out:    int
    fn:         accept num_in positional arguments,
                perform operation,
                return list containing num_out values
    """
    assert num_in  >= 0, "Operator cannot have negative number of arguments"
    self.num_in = num_in
    assert num_out >= 0, "Operator cannot return negative number of results"
    self.num_out = num_out
    self.fn = fn

def __call__(self, stack):
    """
    Run operator against stack (in-place)
    """
    args = stack.pop_n(self.num_in)         # pop num_in arguments
    res = self.fn(*args)                    # pass to function, get results
    stack.push_n(self.num_out, res)         # push num_out values back
ops = {
'*':  Op(2, 1, lambda a,b: [a*b]),          # multiplication
'/':  Op(2, 1, lambda a,b: [a//b]),         # integer division
'+':  Op(2, 1, lambda a,b: [a+b]),          # addition
'-':  Op(2, 1, lambda a,b: [a-b]),          # subtraction
'/%': Op(2, 2, lambda a,b: [a//b, a%b])     # divmod (example of 2-output op)
```

}

```
def postfix_eval(tokens):
"""
Evaluate a series of tokens as a postfix expression;
return the resulting stack
"""
if is_str(tokens):
    # if tokens is a string, treat it as a space-separated list of tokens
    tokens = tokens.split()

stack = Stack()
for token in tokens:
    try:
        # Convert to int and push on stack
        stack.append(int(token))
    except ValueError:
        try:
            # Not an int - must be an operator
            # Get the appropriate operator and run it against the stack
            op = ops[token]
            op(stack)         # runs Op.__call__(op, stack)
        except KeyError:
            # Not a valid operator either
            raise ValueError("unknown operator {}".format(token))
return stack

def main():
while True:
    expr = input(eval('\nEnter a postfix expression (or nothing to quit): ').strip()
    if expr:
        try:
            print("  => {}".format(postfix_eval(expr)))
        except ValueError as error:
            print("Your expression caused an error: {}".format(error))
    else:
        break

if __name__=="__main__":
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/12326/how-to-do-input-in-python. if you try something like

```
raw_input("Enter a postfix expression (or nothing to quit): ")
```

in your main function, it should work better.

cheers,
Peter

Comment: Thanks for help but I run this code in Python 3.2 and If I 'm not mistaken, raw-input is being used in Python 2.x.
Howeever I got an similar error again.(if expr:)

Comment: what does your input look like? why are you doing this eval call inside your input call?

Comment: input(eval('\nEnter a postfix expression (or nothing to quit): ').strip like this.

Comment: why are you using the eval inside of the input? it is just wrapped around the prompt, not around the input read from the user, right?

Comment: nevertheless, can you post a full stack trace of the error occuring?

Comment: I am sorry ı was misunderstood.So can I use like raw_input("Enter a postfix expression (or nothing to quit): ")Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/aa", line 69, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Python27/aa", line 60, in main
    if expr:
NameError: global name 'expr' is not defined

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Python27/aa", line 69, in <module> main() File "C:/Python27/aa", line 60, in main if expr: NameError: global name 'expr' is not defined – I have to define 'exp' The code is the same but ı replaced raw_input("Enter a postfix expression (or nothing to quit): ") instead of expr = input(eval('\nEnter a postfix expression (or nothing to quit): ').strip()

Comment: okay, that means the "expr" variable has not been defined. is there a typo? did you wrote exrp instead of expr or something like this?

Comment: expr=raw_input("Enter a postfix expression (or nothing to quit): ").strip() I defined expr, but I got an error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\aa", line 69, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python27\aa", line 59, in main
    expr=raw_input("Enter a postfix expression (or nothing to quit): ").strip()
NameError: global name 'raw_input' is not defined

Comment: thats confusing me... i copied your expression into my python shell and guess what: it works :-) there must be something weird going on. do you have closed all braces? any indentations not correct?

Comment: which version of Python did you run this expression

Comment: Enter a postfix expression (or nothing to quit): 34+
When I entered a value I'm getting this error in python 2.7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/vnfghf", line 69, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Python27/vnfghf", line 62, in main
    print("  => {}".format(postfix_eval(expr)))
  File "C:/Python27/vnfghf", line 38, in postfix_eval
    if is_str(tokens):
NameError: global name 'is_str' is not defined

Comment: But i would like to run in Python 3.2.I got always an error   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\infix to postfix", line 69, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python32\infix to postfix", line 59, in main
    expr = raw_input('\nEnter a postfix expression (or nothing to quit): ').strip()
NameError: global name 'raw_input' is not defined

Comment: okay, sorry, my fault, try it again with input instead of raw_input. as you noticed before, raw_input has been renamed to input since python 3

Comment: I'm sorry to have wasted your time but I got an error too.

Comment: Enter a postfix expression (or nothing to quit): +34
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\infix to postfix", line 69, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python32\infix to postfix", line 62, in main
    print("  => {}".format(postfix_eval(expr)))
  File "C:\Python32\infix to postfix", line 38, in postfix_eval
    if is_str(tokens):
NameError: global name 'is_str' is not defined

Comment: When I entered a value infix,it didn't change too.Normally it has to run with a value postfix

Comment: have you tried isinstance(tokens, str) instead of is_str?

Comment: Enter a postfix expression (or nothing to quit): +54
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\infix to postfix", line 69, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python32\infix to postfix", line 62, in main
    print("  => {}".format(postfix_eval(expr)))
  File "C:\Python32\infix to postfix", line 42, in postfix_eval
    stack = Stack()
NameError: global name 'Stack' is not defined

Comment: Can you look all this expression,sorry if I bothered you?Because it always turns out a new problem

Comment: you don´t have a class Stack defined, right? where does stack come from?

Comment: btw: it always turn into a new problem is not right.. there are a lot of problems, but the python interpreter stops at the first problem. if this one is fixed, the next problem pops up :)

Comment: How I define a class Stack for these expressions?

Comment: I guess, thats the point to figure out for your homework :-) maybe you take a look at https://www.inkling.com/read/programming-python-mark-lutz-4th/chapter-18/implementing-stacks

Comment: Yeah ı understood,it's a good site but this is hard to define for my expressions.

Comment: sorry, please don't understand me in a wrong way, but i don't think that stack overflow is intended to be a kind of class room. Maybe you should take a look to find a youtube video course about python programming. there are really great hands on videos. sorry, i'm having a leave, good look!

Comment: I found new codes for calculating infix to postfix.But I have a little problem with these codes.I always got an Index error